# How to delete IIS custom headers like X-Powered-By: ASP.NET from response?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-headers

In `IIS 7.0` `integrated mode` after deleting all headers with `Response.ClearHeaders()` IIS would add some other headers like `Server` and `X-Powered-By` which reveals good information to hackers. How can I stop this behavior (consider I still need to add my custom headers) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing/Hiding/Disabling excessive HTTP response headers in Azure/IIS7 without UrlScan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without)

Comment: I know this one was asked first, but that other question is now more complete and up-to-date.

Answer (score 95):

You can add this to your Web.Config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Update: if you're using the MVC framework I would also recommend removing the `X-AspNetMvc-Version` and `X-AspNet-Version` headers as well. This is accomplished by setting `MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true` in your `Global.asax` file and `<system.web><httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" /></system.web>` in your `Web.config` respectively.

Comment: In IIS 10.0 (and Azure Web Apps) you can also get rid of the `Server` header with `<system.webServer><security><requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true"></requestFiltering></security></system.webServer>`.

Comment: Facing similar issue.Added custom header to webconfig file.Locally application runs fine but throw 500 Internal Server error on deployment to IIS server 8.5(AWS) .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947861/webconfig-with-custom-response-header-in-web-config-error-after-deploying-to-iis

Answer (score 14):

The `X-Powered-By` is configured within IIS.  On Windows 7 it's specifically:

1. IIS Manager
2. COMPUTER NAME > Sites > Default Web Site
3. HTTP Respons Headers
4. Remove `X-Powered-By`

I'm not sure what generates the `Server` header though.

Comment: Thanks. At least 50% progress. I prefer a general approach from inside asp.net if possible.

Comment: @Xaqron, you can probably get at the setting programmatically, but I don't know how offhand.  Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

For IIS7+ integrated mode, eth0 has it: `<customHeaders>` tag in web.config. Thanks for that. As for the "Server" header, if using MVC, you can simply add:

```
    protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
        Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    }
```

to your MvcApplication class in Global.asax. Otherwise, you can simply add a custom Http Module, handling the PreSendRequestHeaders event, and do the same thing.

UPDATE: This is not recommended, see comments.

Comment: PreSendRequestHeaders is not a part of the managed pipeline and can produce strange results like frozen asynchronous requests. http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#presend.

Answer (score 5):

Would like to add here that for the ASP.NET Core versions where there is no longer a web.config file a different approach is necessary.

I made the following adjustments to remove the headers in ASP.NET Core 2.1:

You can remove the x-powered-by header by replacing

```
<customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
</customHeaders>
```

with

```
<customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
</customHeaders>
```

in the applicationhost.config file found in the .vs\config folder of the project.

The server header can be removed by adding

```
.UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false)
```

in the Program.cs file.

Answer (score 3):

The following answer includes a complete solution that does not require URLScan or a custom HttpModule, and removes all the related headers you mention. It also works on Azure.

[Removing/Hiding/Disabling excessive HTTP response headers in Azure/IIS7 without UrlScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without)

Answer (score 1):

URLScan can be used to remove server header, or configure another server header, http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/938/urlscan-3-reference/

But it never really prevents a hacker to know what you use in fact. There are obviously other ways to detect your server information.

Comment: Thanks. There should be something built-in like config sections or at worst case registry manipulation rather than installing a component which it's main purpose is not to deleting SERVER headers.

Comment: I already said that not everyone thinks showing server header is bad. So why should it be built in if few people uses it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use appcmd.exe (IIS 7 and above) to do your job. The script will be like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webserver/httpProtocol /-customHeaders.["name='X-Powered-By'"] /commit:apphost
```

`/commit:apphost`: This commits the configuration settings to the appropriate location section in the ApplicationHost.config file.

I usually create a batch file of all these scripts which I run on the web server after the application is installed.

For ASP.NET MVC applications the approach is different and you can refer to other answers given here.