# .m4a is considered audio/m4a or audio/mp4

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I'm trying to make an audio upload to S3 and I'm a little confused what I should declare my mime type as.  My audio file is an m4a recorded on an iphone as `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC`.  Would this be considered `audio/m4a` or `audio/mp4`?  I'm seeing conflicting answers online.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `m4` in `m4a` is short-hand for `MPEG-4`, just like `mp4` is short-hand for `MPEG-4`.

In fact, `m4a`, `m4v` and `mp4` files all have the same internal `MPEG-4` atom structure. The difference between the files is their content (video files have video atoms as well as audio atoms.)

The codec of the audio can also be different despite using the same file extension, for example both `alac` and `AAC` formats use the `MPEG-4` container format with the `m4a` file extension.

So to answer your question, it really doesn't make much difference. My personal preference would be `audio/mp4` since that is effectively saying

> Audio data in MPEG-4 container

Whereas, `audio/m4a` is like saying

> Audio data in MPEG-4 container containing audio

Comment: `audio/m4a` is wrong. See [twhb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58551410/4846592). iOS wouldn't recognize this as `UTType(mimeType: "audio/m4a").conforms(to: .audio) == false`.

Answer (score 24):

Use `audio/mp4`. `audio/m4a` may work, but it's invalid.

[MP4 MIME type registration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4337#page-3):

> ```
> 2.  Selection of MIME Types for MP4 Files
>
>    The MIME types to be assigned to MP4 files are selected according to
>    the contents.  Basic guidelines for selecting MIME types are as
>    follows:
>
>    a) if the file contains neither visual nor audio presentations, but
>       only, for example, MPEG-J or MPEG-7, use application/mp4;
>
>    b) for all other files, including those that have MPEG-J, etc., in
>       addition to video or audio streams, video/mp4 should be used;
>       however:
>
>    c) for files with audio but no visual aspect, including those that
>       have MPEG-J, etc., in addition to audio streams, audio/mp4 may be
>       used.
>
>    In any case, these indicate files conforming to the "MP4"
>    specification, ISO/IEC 14496-1:2000, systems file format.
> ```

Further, [the list of standard MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) includes `audio/mp4`, not `audio/m4a`, and non-standard MIME types should include “x-”, like `audio/x-m4a`.

Comment: Also, `.m4a` is a **nonstandard** extension for an MP4 container.

Answer (score 3):

In 2021 for me `audio/mp4` for an `.m4a` file worked on Firefox + Chrome (Linux), Opera (Android) but not on iPhone Safari. For some formats the OS plays a role due to codecs.
I used a source tag with type attribute set **and I also set the same type in the `Content-Type` header of the streamed / downloaded file**.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Cross-browser_audio_basics
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media

Also see: [How to play .m4a with HTML5 audio in IE(9+) and Safari (Pad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269791/how-to-play-m4a-with-html5-audio-in-ie9-and-safari-pad)

Comment: `audio/x-m4a` just worked for me on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

audio/m4a is not in MIME list, truely, shoude be audio/mp4. If set m4a, please set audio/x-m4a.