# Unable to play m4a on Windows

Tags: html, html5-audio, mime-types, m4a

I have an audio file recorded from the iPhone's Voice Memos app (`.m4a`, compressed). I'm trying to get it to play on any device using the `audio` tag.

```html
<audio ...>
  <source src={file.href} type="audio/x-m4a" />
</audio>
```

The file is saved on the backend where the mimetype shows as `audio/x-m4a`.

This was working when the page is opened from an Apple device like an iPhone. But on a Windows machine, Chrome can't play it - the controls are grayed out like it was unable to load the file.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58551410/5530965) and it seems like I need to use `audio/mp4` for m4a files. I created a utility function:

```js
static fixMimeType = (mimeType: string) => {
  if (mimeType.toLowerCase() === 'video/quicktime') {
    // Use video/mp4 for .mov files
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858204/5530965
    return 'video/mp4';
  }

  if (mimeType.toLowerCase() === 'audio/x-m4a' || mimeType.toLowerCase() === 'audio/m4a') {
    // Use audio/mp4 for .m4a files
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/58551410/5530965
    return 'audio/mp4';
  }

  return mimeType;
};
```

But even if I change the mimetype to `audio/mp4` it still doesn't play on Windows, but it's still fine on iPhone.

Comment: I'd recommend checking if your Windows and the broswer are up-to-date. And maybe check if the issue persists on different browsers. If needed, you can use a free online tool that converts [m4a to mp3](https://cloudconvert.com/m4a-to-mp3). Also, if the file isn't hosted online, check the file permissions for the browser. If it is a local file it can be blocked because of security reasons.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: @dokgu For Chrome test by using: `type="audio/mpeg"` ... If the file is still not playing, then test with a short different M4A (few seconds) , does the short one work? If yes, then tell us how many bytes in your "not working" file?