# how to remove server info via <customHeaders> in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have removed the x-powered-by using  `<httpProtocol>`

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
       <remove name="Server" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This hides  the `X-Powered-By` but the server (IIS info ) is still not getting removed

**It would be good if there is a way where I can remove all the info in the `Response Header`**

How can i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing/Hiding/Disabling excessive HTTP response headers in Azure/IIS7 without UrlScan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without)

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without/21064912#21064912) for how to do this without UrlScan.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need **[UrlScan](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326444)** to remove the IIS info.

The particular setting you need to configure is: **RemoveServerHeader**

> By default, a Web server returns a header that identifies what Web
>   server software it is running in all responses. This can increase the
>   server vulnerability because an attacker can determine that a server
>   is running IIS and then attack known IIS problems, instead of trying
>   to attack an IIS server by using exploits that are designed for other
>   Web servers. By default, this option is set to 0. If you set the
>   RemoveServerHeader option to 1, you prevent your server from sending
>   the header that identifies it as an IIS server. If you set
>   RemoveServerHeader to 0, this header is still sent.

Comment: The problem is I dont have control over the server.
Thats why I am trying to do it via the application

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't be possible.