# Remove cache HTTP response headers from Web Api in Azure

Tags: iis, azure, http-headers

I am trying to remove unwanted Cache-Control, Pragma and Expires HTTP headers in responses from a Web Api 2 project hosted on an Azure website in Standard mode.

I have tried the following in **Global.asax Application_PreSendRequestHeaders**:

```
var headers = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Response.Headers;
headers.Remove("Cache-Control");
headers.Remove("Pragma");
headers.Remove("Expires");
```

This works when debugging in Visual Studio. But on Azure, the headers are only removed for GET requests and not HEAD or POST requests.

Grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12803974/268066) to another question says you may have to use `Application_BeginRequest` instead of `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders`.
It also reenforces that many headers cannot be modified via `<customHeaders>` as suggested by @Mark Rendle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing/Hiding/Disabling excessive HTTP response headers in Azure/IIS7 without UrlScan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without)

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web Sites supports the request filtering module, so you can do this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <remove name="Cache-Control" />
      <remove name="Pragma" />
      <remove name="Expires" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

**Disclaimer: I am not condoning the removal of these headers, which are an essential part of the HTTP protocol.**

Removing cache headers says to clients "it is entirely up to you to decide how to cache this response", which may result in odd and hard-to-reproduce errors in production. If you want to disable caching, you should set these headers to values which explicitly disable caching:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
      <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
      <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried. Unfortunately, these headers don't seem to be removed by this technique (applies to both Azure and local development server). The principle is solid as I am already removing the X-Powered-By header this way. I wonder what's going on with these headers?!

Comment: As I say, these are important headers. Why are you looking to remove them rather than setting them to specific values?

Comment: The only consumer of this API is a proprietary hardware device that has no concept of caching. So the headers are redundant.

Comment: Considering pragma: no-cache was never supposed to be a response header and Microsoft stopped recommending its use in [2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/165150)  I don't really consider it essential.  And Expires: -1 is an invalid header that duplicates what Cache-Control does, it also can be safely removed. I believe.