# How to remove my server signature IIS 7 with NWebsec nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, nuget-package, nwebsec

I am trying to hide my server signature Microsoft IIS:7 from my websites. I searched too much, lots of links, code suggestions and articles, but none of them works for my Asp.net MVC project. I found a suggestion here [Removing/Hiding/Disabling excessive HTTP response headers in Azure/IIS7 without UrlScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without)

that maybe a Nuget package named NWebsec do it. I added this package to the project and and then it added some new codes to my `web.config`. The problem is that the project works fine in offline mode, but when I upload the published files in host server, it has error on line 24 which it is this

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

I think it may have some conflict with something named owin which it added. Appreciate any help for this question or any other way suggested to remove my host name from my website.

Comment: Please update question with error that you are getting on line 24

Comment: @MohsinMehmood thank you very much for your care. the error is `Configuration Error` and the explain is `It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I did `<customErrors mode="Off" />` but still no more information for what the error is . I really need Help please

Comment: Is your application configured as a separate website in IIS or as a Virtual Directory or sub application under IIS website?

Comment: it is a separate website in the GoDaddy host. but the host is a kind which it supports different websites and domains and one host. thank you very much. I really need help. @MohsinMehmood

Comment: Ok `<authentication mode="None" />` do you really need it? Does your website uses any authentication? You can try removing it from web.config

Comment: @MohsinMehmood thank you nice suggestion. I removed it and now it has 404 Error. Page not found. let me check in offline to be sure what is the error

Comment: @MohsinMehmood my purpose of all these efforts is to find a way to turn my server signature off. it is Microsoft IIS 7 and I want to hide it , I appreciate any other way if it works really. I searched a lot and tried many ways but none of them works. Appreciate if you could help me in this way

Comment: @MohsinMehmood it works fine in offline after removing `<authentication mode="None" />`